# Bug or design issue in Stack Overflow's badges section

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, badges

I have seen a design bug in the Stack Overflow BADGES section.

After earning a badge the design flows like the screenshot below:

[image: Design bug screenshot]

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes it is possible duplicate of a question which has a answer having -3 vote. :D

Comment: Having a downvoted answer doesn't make it not a duplicate. When it comes to bugs, we don't need 6 separate reports open at once. :)... and there have been many duplicates for this bug over the last week it's existed.